# Need to create dynamic pivot in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have the below query which is running fine, but its a static pivot. I want to create it dynamically. I wanted to know what are the changes this code required so that I can make it a dynamic pivot.
Thanks in advance!!!!

```
select * from
    (
select g.NationalityName_1,DepartmentName_1,h.EmployeeID from HR_Department hr
            join
HR_EmploymentInformation h
    on h.DepartmentID=hr.DepartmentID
        join
HR_EmployeeDetail e
    on e.EmployeeID=h.EmployeeID
        join
GEN_Nationality g
    on g.NationalityID=e.DefaultNationalityID
) as fev
pivot 
(
    count(employeeId)
    for departmentname_1 in (Administration,Academia,[New Department 1],[New Department 2],[New Department 3],[New Department 5])
) as pvt
```

This is the output:

```
NationalityName_1   Administration  Academia    New Department 1    New Department 2    New Department 3    New Department 5
Algeria                 0            1          0                   0                   0                   0
```

This is the output of the above query and its the correct one, problem I am facing is If I create a new department I have to again change in a code which I don't want.

Comment: If I provide you the dynamic solution then can you apply that in your code ?? because without sample data and expected output it's very hard to deal with it.

Comment: Yes I can run the query..

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** We can write dynamic `PIVOT` in the following way

```
DECLARE @col VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @col = COALESCE(@col + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(DepartmentName_1)
FROM HR_Department hr
JOIN HR_EmploymentInformation h ON h.DepartmentID = hr.DepartmentID
JOIN HR_EmployeeDetail e ON e.EmployeeID = h.EmployeeID
JOIN GEN_Nationality g ON g.NationalityID = e.DefaultNationalityID

SET @sql = '
    SELECT NationalityName_1, ' + @col + '
    FROM
        (SELECT g.NationalityName_1,
            DepartmentName_1,
            h.EmployeeID 
        FROM HR_Department hr
        JOIN HR_EmploymentInformation h ON h.DepartmentID = hr.DepartmentID
        JOIN HR_EmployeeDetail e ON e.EmployeeID = h.EmployeeID
        JOIN GEN_Nationality g ON g.NationalityID = e.DefaultNationalityID
        ) AS fev
    PIVOT 
    (
        COUNT(employeeId)
        FOR departmentname_1 IN ( ' + @col + ' )
    ) AS pvt'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but it is giving me an error. I am not able to post my query in comment I don't know why

Comment: Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Acad'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'Acad'.  It is giving an error

Comment: I think there is `,` or `"` something alike exist in the data. Can you please check, though it would better if you provide sample data in your question.